# Android espresso test full screen message

Tags: android, android-espresso

**Android espresso tests**
when i am running tests on emulator i have the android system view appearing from time to time and this view makes my test to fail.
how can i ignore it?

in the image i added you can see the message [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9otbo.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the containsString() in Espresso Library to find the text present on screen before running the test cases. If present then perform click action on button or outside .

Use containsString in your method on a TextView:

```
textView.check(matches(withText(containsString("Test"))));
```